# Mvc WebApi Querystring to a AddPost method

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, controller, query-string, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm trying to get the querystring that is in the browser, 
an example /UserHome/UserProfile?username=**dangercoder**. I'm working in WebApi controller

from the following url i want to get "dangercoder" so I can use the dangercoder username in my AddPost method that is in my Web Api

what i've done so far in the method (the reciever id can be hardcoded but ofcourse i want it to be dangercoder username converted to an id.

```
  [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
  public IHttpActionResult AddPost(Post post)
  {
       if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           return BadRequest(ModelState);
       }            
       var user = User.Identity.Name;
       post.SenderID = UserRepository.GetUserId(user);
       // QueryString that returns username in the parameter below.
       post.RecieverID = UserRepository.GetUserId();
       PostRepository.AddNewPost(post);
       return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = post.ID }, post);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, the view `UserProfile` contains HTML form with `Post` fields.

You may create hidden field `SenderId` in the form with user's ID.

Comment: I'm using a partial view called PostView fyi

Comment: Has this view a model of the type `Post`? Just assing desired value to `Model.SenderId` in the `UserProfile` action.

Comment: This view model is of the type Post, indeed.

Comment: Does you include the partial view like this: `@Html.Partial("PostView", new Post())`? You can use `@Html.Partial("PostView", new Post { SenderId = UserId })` and then use `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SenderId)` in `PostView`.